# Nginx rewrite /path to /

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have service A run in port 8080 and service B run in port 8081. I want to set up a nginx proxy so when I access http://localhost/serviceA it will redirect to service A and when I access http://localhost/serviceB it will redirect to service B.
Service A doesn't have /serviceA path same with service B doesn't have path /serviceB. Both service only have / path.

Answer (score 0):

Iry this:

```
server {
    location /serviceA {
       proxy_pass http://serviceA:8080/;
    }
    location /serviceB {
       proxy_pass http://serviceB:8081/;
    }
}
```

With this configuration we have for example:

```
/serviceA/ -> /
/ServiceA/bla -> /bla
```